# how to test a function that returns Dataset[String, T]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

hello i have the following function returns a Dataset[(String, SubsidiariesImpactedStage)]:

`def reduceSubsidiaries(dsSubsidiaries: Dataset[SubsidiariesImpactedStage]): Dataset[(String, SubsidiariesImpactedStage)] = {}`

`SubsidiariesImpactedStage` is the following

```
case class SubsidiariesImpactedStage(
  event_timestamp: Timestamp,
  event_type: String,
  subsidiary_uuid: String,
  subsidiary_id: Long,
  company_uuid: String
)
```

this is my following test i've written

```
  val ts1 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-08-01 00:00:00")
      val ts2 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-09-20 00:00:00")
      val ts3 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-11-27 00:00:00")
      val subsidiaries = Seq(
        SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts1,"active","sub_uuid1",32L,"comp_uuid1"),
        SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts2, "inactive","sub_uuid1",32L, "comp_uuid1"),
        SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts3, "active", "sub_uuid1", 5L, "latest_comp_uuid1")
      ).toDS()

      val actual:Dataset[(String, SubsidiariesImpactedStage)] = reduceSubsidiaries(subsidiaries)
      val expected: Dataset[(String, SubsidiariesImpactedStage)] = Seq(
        SubsidiariesImpactedStage(ts3,"active","sub_uuid1", 5L, "latest_comp_uuid1")
      ).toDS()
```

I get an error on my `expected` becuase it is `Dataset[SubsidiaresImpactedStage]` and not `Dataset[(String, SubsidiariesImpactedStage)]`, how would i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The left side of the last command defines `expected` as of tuples `Dataset[(String, SubsidiariesImpactedStage)]`.

The right side assigns `Dataset[SubsidiariesImpactedStage]`.

Try to change your right side to

```
val expected: Dataset[(String, SubsidiariesImpactedStage)] = Seq(("myString",
  SubsidiariesImpactedStage("active","sub_uuid1", 5L, "latest_comp_uuid1")
  )
).toDS()
```

The `"myString"` is whatever string you consider relevant for your `expected`.